# What modules are used by Open Atrium 2?

Tags: distributions

I am looking for a list of the modules in the standard Open Atrium 2 install, something similar to those posted for Drupal Commons and Acquia Commons like:

https://drupal.org/node/2160755
https://docs.acquia.com/commons/module

Is one available? Where is it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a set of drush make files in the [project directory](http://drupalcode.org/project/openatrium.git/tree/refs/heads/7.x-2.x). Those list the various dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Install it locally and via drush do `drush pml` and it will tell you all installed modules. Not every distribution lists dependencies, they assume you can track it down. It's dependant on their own OA_* modules (and their dependencies) and the Panpoly distribution. http://drupalcode.org/project/openatrium.git/blob/HEAD:/drupal-org.make

You could always make a support request and supply the list yourself to their Project Issue Queue and help the project documentation along after you checkout `pml` via drush.